# Getting workspace path in Notepad++ run commands

Tags: command, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ with workspaces, created through "Open Folder as Workspace".

I am trying to launch external command from Notepad++ using the Run command menu.

The variable `FULL_CURRENT_PATH` give me the current file path but I need to get the worskpace path to launch some deployment script in the root of the workspace.

Is there a variable for workspace path ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no such variable. You can see a list of all variables in the source code of Notpad++:

https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/StaticDialog/RunDlg/RunDlg.cpp

You can read the Workspace directories from the configuration file, but the file will only be written if Notepad ++ is closed. Maybe someone has an idea how to trigger that

```
cmd /c echo. |powershell -Command [xml]$nb = Get-Content $env:appdata\Notepad++\config.xml; Write-Output $nb.NotepadPlus.FileBrowser.root.foldername
```